# JWT.decode returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, decode

I am trying to decode JSON web token but it returns null. I even tried with complete set to true but still it fails.

Function used to generate token:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

jwt.sign({ id: 5a2fa889c546431ccc5692e1,
firstName: 'hemadri',
lastName: 'dasari',
email: 'hemadri.dasari1990@gmail.com',
role: 'Member',
sex: 'male',
dob: undefined,
authenticated: true }, "pemmasaniDasari")

{token: 
"JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhMmZhODg5YzU0NjQzMWNjYzU2OTJlMSIsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6ImhlbWFkcmkiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6ImRhc2FyaSIsImVtYWlsIjoiaGVtYWRyaS5kYXNhcmkxOTkwQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJNZW1iZXIiLCJzZXgiOiJtYWxlIiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCI6dHJ1ZSwiaWF0IjoxNTE0MzQyNDQ0fQ.LRMJXUvW7TdPdpoet53Wm6SQYX3VuNYZ_wJHfujbxfY"}
version: "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0"
```

Function that I used to decode is:

```
jwt.decode(token)
```

Comment: First things first: where does `jwt.sign` come from? What is the **exact** result returned by `jwt.sign`? (it totally cannot be an object you provided)

Comment: What call are you making to decode?

Comment: @zerkms Updated my post properly. I made a silly mistake. Your second question helped me realize it. The issue was while generating token I have appended few characters to it (you can see that in the start of the token) i.e., JWT. Which was actually causing an issue. I am able to decode the token now post removing JWT from the token. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was while generating token I have appended few characters to it (you can see that in the start of the token) i.e., JWT in my Original Post. Which was actually causing an issue. I am able to decode it now post removing JWT from the token.